# Unnecessary delete on @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, many-to-many, cascade

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_ENTITY_1")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="entity1", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Entity2> list;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        schema="schema",
        name="V_OTHER_RELATIONSHIP", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID_ENTITY_1", insertable=false, updatable=false)}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(
                name="ID_ENTITY_2",
                referencedColumnName="ID_ENTITY_2",
                insertable=false, updatable=false
            )
        }
    )

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_ENTITY_2")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ENTITY_1)
    private Entity1 entity1;

    //getters e setters.
}
```

Note that not exists cascade in @ManyToMany relationship through the V_OTHER_RELATIONSHIP.

But, when i execute one delete on Entity1, the first thing that occurres is one delete in V_OTHER_RELATIONSHIP that causes an error because it is readonly.

Help-me.

Comment: I don't understand, you cannot delete Entity1 if there is something referencing it in the database, so how can this relationship via a join table work?  If you want entries in the join table to live on after the referencing entity is deleted, the join table should be mapped as an entity instead.

Comment: The reference to Entity1 is a view.

Comment: I do not want delete in the view (V_OTHER_RELATIONSHIP).

Comment: Right, so then it isn't a join table.  Since it isn't a join table and you want it to exist outside of the Entity1 <--> Entity2 relationship, you should map it as an entity.  Entity1 <---> V_Other_Relationship_Entity <--> Entity2